# If-else condition in JavaScript more dynamic

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a JavaScript code which has many if-else conditions for different brands w.r.t html

```
function get_brand_label(b) {
    var brand1label = '<div class="brand1_label">B1</div>';
    var brand2label = '<div class="brand2_label">B2</div>';
    var brand3label = '<div class="brand3_label">B3</div>';
    var brand4label = '<div class="brand4_label">B4</div>';

    if (b == 'Brand1') {
        return brand1label;
    } else if (b == 'Brand2') {
        return brand2label;
    } else if (b == 'Brand3') {
        return brand3label;
    } else if (b == 'Brand4') {
        return brand4label;
    }
}
```

I am using this get_brand_label function in another function as:

```
var label = get_brand_label(d.brand);
```

In future, if I want to add B5 and B6, I need to add new if-else conditions

So before adding new brands, is there any way to make the above existing code more dynamic so that I don't need to add if-else conditions in future while adding new brands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make a map of labels and brands and then return the label based on the brand:

```
const brandLabelMap = {
  Brand1: '<div class="brand1_label">B1</div>',
  Brand2: '<div class="brand2_label">B2</div>',
  Brand3: '<div class="brand3_label">B3</div>',
  Brand4: '<div class="brand4_label">B4</div>'
};

function get_brand_label(b) {
  return brandLabelMap[b];
}
```

Comment: is it ok to put const inside that function ?

Comment: Yea, if you want it to be available only in the scope of that function.

Comment: Got it, but how do I use this function in another function ```var label = get_brand_label(d.brand);``` ?

Comment: That works if `d.brand` is a string, like Brand1', etc.

Comment: ```var d = 'Brand1'; console.log(get_brand_label(d));``` is not working

Comment: it works, returns `<div class="brand1_label">B1</div>`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197457/discussion-between-saash-techs-and-clarity).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    const yourFunction = (label) => {
      return label + "label";
    }
    yourFunction(label);
```

you don't even need if\else you can return label + your brand.

Comment: This does not return the HTML string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `object` instead, add the extra key/value pairs when you want to extend it

```js
function get_brand_label(b) {
    let mapping = {
      'Brand1': '<div class="brand1_label">B1</div>',
      'Brand2': '<div class="brand1_label">B2</div>',
      'Brand3': '<div class="brand1_label">B3</div>',
      'Brand4': '<div class="brand1_label">B4</div>',
    }
  return mapping[b]
}

console.log(get_brand_label('Brand2'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others have suggested, use an object to map key-value-pairs and construct your HTML from it, like so:

```js
function get_brand_label(b) {
  const brandlabels = {
    "Brand1" : "B1",
    "Brand2" : "B2",
    "Brand3" : "B3",
    "Brand4" : "B4",
  };
  
  return `<div class="${b.toLowerCase()}_label">${brandlabels[b]}</div>`;
}

console.log(get_brand_label("Brand1"));
```

---

`${b.toLowerCase()}_label` will automatically create lower-case classnames. However if your brands contain spaces or other characters that are not valid for css you need to take care of that, too.